# Python3 script runs fine in console but won't work while executed by crontab

Tags: python, linux, command-line, cron

I'm trying to get the following script to run successfull on crontab but it won't work.

```
*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/secret_directory/main.py > /home/USER/grabber.log
```

I tried to just run the command in SSH and it worked:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/secret_directory/main.py
```

If it works the outputs should look like this:

```
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 61/61 [00:16<00:00,  3.62it/s]
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1696/1696 [01:09<00:00, 24.30it/s]
```

but it looks like this in the grabber.log file:

```
  0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  3.60it/s]
100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  3.59it/s]
```

I don't know if it is important but it is about this software: https://github.com/RedBlaze42/Mars2020-images-downloader

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem seems purely aesthetic. If you don't want the script to attempt to format progress bars, take out those parts from the Python script. They are meant for interactive use so they are obviously rather useless in a `cron` job, and the end result won't render correctly if you don't view it in a terminal which supports the formatting codes used by the script.

Comment: Well the first progress bar is checking the Image Urls from the NASA API, the second one is the actual download of those images. When running via cron the images won't be downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take out the calls to `tqdm`; replace anything whict looks like `tqdm(whatever)` with just `whatever`.

https://tqdm.github.io/ is a library for displaying "friendly" progress meters, but that's obviously only useful for interactive programs, and problematic when you want to run the code in a place where there is no terminal.